# Do a search efficiently across a dictionary of string values?

Tags: c#

I have a large dictionary of pre-computed values of type  in a C# dictionary.

Now I have a search string, I need to find all entries in the dictionary where the search string is part of "string" value.i.e Say I have,

```
Dictionary<PersonId, PersonDescription> values;
```

Search string is "office" I would need to find all entries in the dictionary where PersonDescription string value contains the term "office".

How best to search in the fastest way possible?

Comment: Try to look for custom comparer,  look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8400865/335905

Comment: LINQ's Where method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are optimised on accessing by the *key*.  So, you're going to have to iterate over every single element anyway to see if the value contains the key.  Here's two potential ways:

**Iterate**

```
List<PersonDescription> found = new List<PersonDescription>();
foreach(var pair in values)
{
   if(pair.Value.SomeField.Contains("office"))
       found.Add(pair.Value);
}
```

Note that the above adds the `PersonDescription`, you might want to add `PersonId`.

**Use a [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class (and then iterate)**

You'll have to derived a class from this (but it's simple) (also assumes `PersonId` is a member of `PersonDescription`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic.ObjectModel

public class PersonDictionary : KeyedCollection<int, PersonDescription>
{
    protected override int GetKeyforItem(PersonDescription description)
    {
        return description.Personid; // hope it's on this class!
    }
}
```

Now you can iterate over this, and also access it randomly:

```
List<PersonDescription> found = new List<PersonDescription>();
for(int i = 0; i < values.Count; ++i)
{
    if(values[i].Field.Contains("office"))
        found.Add(values[i]);
}
```

You can substitute the manual loops specified above for LINQ if you prefer.

Dictionaries are generally used because you want a fast look up by a *key*.  I am not saying this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but it smells like it.  Alternatively you might actually need to access a dictionary both by key and by searching all items

Comment: Hi Moo-Juice...you may be right...its been a long day. Basically, I have a long list of PersonId, PersonDesc string values in a csv file and I need to perform sort of a fast search for items in the file that match the search string as part of PersonDesc, Ideally I would need an index I believe but as a first pass, thought Id use a dictionary to load up the values.

Comment: (unless I'm mistaken) neither of these will make a partial string match (like `Field.Contains("office")` instead of `Field == "office"`) any faster than iterating through a `List<>`. `Dictionary` and its hash-based brethren are great for *exact* matches, not *inexact* ones. Maybe you could use an appropriate dictionary/lookup for a quick exact search before the longer inexact one...

Comment: @TimS., I am assuming that *in general* he wants to access using an id, but also wants to perform searches.  I believe `KeyedCollection` might help here, but you're right - I doubt it'll be any more different than a `List<>`.  However, I don't have all his use-cases in front of me :)

Comment: Thanks @TimS. Any suggestions on any other datastructures that I could use...I would prefer ready-made ones part of C# .Net 4.0

Comment: I will definitely look into that @TimS. That actually looks like something I should be looking at. Thank you all for your suggestions. I will mark this as the answer...Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
string searchTerm = "office";
var PeopleIDs = dict.Where(person => person.Value.Contains(searchTerm))
                    .Select(item => item.Key);
```

Do you want something more complex than that?